# Why did the creators of C decide to support one statement while loops without braces?

Tags: c

I am reading *The C Programming Language* (K&R) and noticed C allows the use of while loops preceding a single statement to function without any braces; why did the creators of C decide to support this? I presume this introduces some extra complexity for the compiler, is the desire for single statement while loops so common (for readability, perhaps?) it was worth whatever trade-off was required to allow them?

Comment: It allows concision, and there is little or no trade-off in compiler complexity. The body of a loop is simply a statement, and a block (a brace-enclosed list of statements and/or declarations) is simply one kind of statement.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't add any special complexity to the compiler, and it's not just while loops. All of the control structures (if, for, while, etc.) govern a "statement", where a block is just a special case of a statement (called a "compound-statement") containing 0 or more declarations or statements. There isn't any specific use case or rationale for applying this rule to `while`, but none is really needed, other than maybe simplicity or consistency.

Comment: I guess the exception is a function body: it has to be a compound statement, not merely a statement.

Comment: I suppose otherwise `void foo(void) ;` would be ambiguous: is it a declaration, or a definition whose body is the statement `;`?

Comment: @NateEldredge — And in old pre-standard C, you wrote (or, at least, you could write): `main(argc, argv) char **argv; { … }`.  No need for a return type; that was `int` by default.  No need to declare the type of `argc`; that too was `int` by default.  The compound statement in braces was necessary with that notation.